# Why is apt autoremove not correctly undoing apt install?

Tags: apt, libreoffice

I am on xubuntu 22.04. When I install libreoffice with dependencies, it takes up 682 MB of space. When I then immediately remove it with --purge and --autoremove flags, it only frees up 387MB of space, leaving many packages. Why? And how do I fix it going forward?

I then manually uninstalled the rest of the packages, freeing up the remaining 296 MB.

```
~$ sudo apt install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc firebird3.0-server-core firebird3.0-utils fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-extra
  fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-noto-extra fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 java-common libabw-0.1-1 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbsh-java libcdr-0.1-1 libe-book-0.1-1
  libel-api-java libepubgen-0.1-1 libfbclient2 libfreehand-0.1-1 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libhsqldb1.8.0-java libib-util libjsp-api-java liblibreoffice-java libmspub-0.1-1 libmysqlclient21 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libpq5
  libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-math libreoffice-nlpsolver libreoffice-report-builder libreoffice-report-builder-bin
  libreoffice-script-provider-bsh libreoffice-script-provider-js libreoffice-script-provider-python libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-sdbc-mysql libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libreoffice-style-elementary
  libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-wiki-publisher libreoffice-writer libservlet-api-java libservlet3.1-java libtommath1 libunoloader-java libvisio-0.1-1 libwebsocket-api-java libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless ure-java
Suggested packages:
  firebird3.0-server firebird3.0-doc java-virtual-machine libhsqldb1.8.0-java-gcj gpa imagemagick | graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat libreoffice-grammarcheck libreoffice-help libreoffice-l10n libreoffice-librelogo myspell-dictionary
  openclipart-libreoffice pstoedit unixodbc gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-libav libsane1 libofficebean-java libjtds-java libsqliteodbc | tdsodbc | odbc-mdbtools
  libreoffice-evolution seahorse libreofficekit-data bluez default-mysql-server | virtual-mysql-server postgresql mediawiki fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc firebird3.0-server-core firebird3.0-utils fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-extra
  fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-noto-extra fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 java-common libabw-0.1-1 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbsh-java libcdr-0.1-1 libe-book-0.1-1
  libel-api-java libepubgen-0.1-1 libfbclient2 libfreehand-0.1-1 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libhsqldb1.8.0-java libib-util libjsp-api-java liblibreoffice-java libmspub-0.1-1 libmysqlclient21 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libpq5
  libreoffice libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-math libreoffice-nlpsolver libreoffice-report-builder
  libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-script-provider-bsh libreoffice-script-provider-js libreoffice-script-provider-python libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-sdbc-mysql libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
  libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-wiki-publisher libreoffice-writer libservlet-api-java libservlet3.1-java libtommath1 libunoloader-java libvisio-0.1-1 libwebsocket-api-java libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3
  openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless ure-java
0 upgraded, 72 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 165 MB of archives.
After this operation, 682 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

```
~$ sudo apt remove --purge --autoremove libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fonts-dejavu* fonts-linuxlibertine* fonts-noto-extra* fonts-sil-gentium* fonts-sil-gentium-basic* gstreamer1.0-gl* gstreamer1.0-gtk3* libbsh-java* libcdr-0.1-1* libfreehand-0.1-1* libgraphene-1.0-0* libgstreamer-gl1.0-0*
  libmspub-0.1-1* libpagemaker-0.0-0* libreoffice* libreoffice-draw* libreoffice-gnome* libreoffice-gtk3* libreoffice-impress* libreoffice-nlpsolver* libreoffice-script-provider-bsh* libreoffice-script-provider-js*
  libreoffice-script-provider-python* libreoffice-wiki-publisher* libvisio-0.1-1*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 25 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 387 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

```
~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
~$ sudo apt remove --purge --autoremove ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc firebird3.0-server-core firebird3.0-utils fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-noto-extra fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 java-common libabw-0.1-1 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbsh-java libcdr-0.1-1 libe-book-0.1-1 libel-api-java libepubgen-0.1-1 libfbclient2 libfreehand-0.1-1 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libhsqldb1.8.0-java libib-util libjsp-api-java liblibreoffice-java libmspub-0.1-1 libmysqlclient21 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libpq5 libreoffice libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-math libreoffice-nlpsolver libreoffice-report-builder libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-script-provider-bsh libreoffice-script-provider-js libreoffice-script-provider-python libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-sdbc-mysql libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-wiki-publisher libreoffice-writer libservlet-api-java libservlet3.1-java libtommath1 libunoloader-java libvisio-0.1-1 libwebsocket-api-java libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless ure-java
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gstreamer1.0-gl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libcdr-0.1-1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libfreehand-0.1-1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libgraphene-1.0-0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libgstreamer-gl1.0-0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libmspub-0.1-1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpagemaker-0.0-0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libvisio-0.1-1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fonts-dejavu' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fonts-linuxlibertine' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fonts-noto-extra' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fonts-sil-gentium' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fonts-sil-gentium-basic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libbsh-java' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gstreamer1.0-gtk3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-draw' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-gnome' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-gtk3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-impress' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-nlpsolver' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-script-provider-bsh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-script-provider-js' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-script-provider-python' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libreoffice-wiki-publisher' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ca-certificates-java* default-jre* default-jre-headless* firebird3.0-common* firebird3.0-common-doc* firebird3.0-server-core* firebird3.0-utils* fonts-crosextra-caladea* fonts-crosextra-carlito* fonts-dejavu-extra* java-common*
  libabw-0.1-1* libatk-wrapper-java* libatk-wrapper-java-jni* libe-book-0.1-1* libel-api-java* libepubgen-0.1-1* libfbclient2* libhsqldb1.8.0-java* libib-util* libjsp-api-java* liblibreoffice-java* libmysqlclient21* libpq5*
  libreoffice-base* libreoffice-base-drivers* libreoffice-java-common* libreoffice-math* libreoffice-report-builder* libreoffice-report-builder-bin* libreoffice-sdbc-firebird* libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb* libreoffice-sdbc-mysql*
  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql* libreoffice-style-elementary* libreoffice-style-yaru* libreoffice-writer* libservlet-api-java* libservlet3.1-java* libtommath1* libunoloader-java* libwebsocket-api-java* libwpd-0.10-10* libwpg-0.3-3*
  openjdk-11-jre* openjdk-11-jre-headless* ure-java*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 47 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 296 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: You have a more important problem: `...and 70 not upgraded`

Comment: Indeed, test first on a fully updated system. What does a subsequent `sudo apt autoremove`produce?

Comment: I upgraded all my packages and updated the question to match, the issue still happens. @vanadium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how the packages that are pulled in as dependencies are being marked. Packages can be marked as *automatically* installed, or *manually* installed. Thus, a package you explicitly install, is marked as manually installed. A package that you attempt to install while it is already installed and marked as automatically installed, will be marked as manually installed. Important to realize is that dependencies pulled in during installation of a package are not necessarily marked as automatically installed. And the latter explains your observation.

Marking automatically installed dependencies as manually installed is used to prevent undesired issues when autoremoving dependencies. A prime example of this is with metapackages, e.g. `ubuntu-desktop`. A metapackage merely serves as a list of components that make up, in this case, a default Ubuntu desktop. Removing one component of the default desktop will remove the metapackage. It is not desired that a subsuquent autoremove then takes down the whole desktop. Thus, the "top level" packages listed in the metapackage are marked as manually installed, so they remain on the system even if the metapackage is removed.

You are seeing something similarly happening when installing libreoffice. Selected packages that are pulled as a dependency of the `libreoffice` package and their dependencies are also marked as manually installed. Which ones is decided upon by the package developers during package preparation.

So it is not only the system administrator's actions, but also the way the packages have been defined by the developers that define automatic package installation and removal.

Answer (score 0):

tldr; I can not confirm that.

I've created a fresh new/clean ubuntu 22.04.

Counting the installed packages:

```bash
sudo dpkg -l | wc -l 
600
```

okay 600 packages, next let's install libreoffice

```bash
sudo apt install libreoffice

...
317 newly installed
```

317 new packages will be installed.
finishing the installation, let's count again the installed packages:

```bash
sudo  dpkg -l | wc -l
917
```

600+317 = 917

seems okay.

Now let's remove and purge libreoffice

```bash
sudo apt -y autoremove --purge libreoffice

...

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 317 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1448 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 

...
```

> 317 to remove

and last counting again the installed packages:

```bash
sudo dpkg -l | wc -l
600
```